# Why kernel log is empty?

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, kernel

My macOS 10.12.3 crashed while suspended and I want to look in the log files to determine where the problem comes from.

I opened System Information and in the Logs I found a Kernel log entry linked to `/var/log/asl`. But this file is empty. Why?

Answer (score 5):

As of 10.12, macOS no longer primarily logs to text files.  However, you can interrogate the stored log data using the `log(1)` command on the command line in concert with the Console application (found in `/Applications/Utilities`).

For example, to see all log entries generated by the kernel during the last day in old-fashioned syslog-style text, you can do:

```
log show --predicate 'processImagePath contains "kernel"' --style syslog --last 1d
```

(You can also use `--start` and `--end` flags if you want to restrict the time window more accurately.)

Alternatively, you can collect all logs from the past day into a bundle called `system_logs.logarchive` in the current directory by doing:

```
sudo log collect --last 1d
```

You can then open this bundle in the Console app (this takes a little while), and in the Search field type `process:kernel` to find all the log entries generated by the kernel.

I suggest a thorough reading of the `log(1)` man page (as well as the other resources it points to), plus some experimentation.

Comment: This is hard work, I miss the old `kernel.log` .

Answer (score 1):

Likely because on MacOS, this log is located at `/private/var/log/asl`

Here is a tip that I use: given symlinks and hidden folders (plus confusing Unix man), it can be a challenge to find these logs and system reports. Simply open Console, and you will see a list of all the logs and reports.(you will find the one you want under the heading `/var/log`). Simply right click on the log, and choose 'Reveal in Finder' and it will open directly to the log location!